# SharePoint link to a shared drive folder not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, links

I am trying to create a quick link to a folder on our share drive:

[image]

Does O365 SharePoint not support links to file drives anymore?

How can I create a link to our drive???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't link to a drive letter in SharePoint Online, as far as I know. You might be able to use a [UNC-style](http://unc.us/) link, e. g.

```
\\servername\share_point\directory_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use either the file:// protocol or UNC paths in SharePoint Online.  The field will let you input a file:// or UNC path, but after submission, when you click on the link or view the page source:

1. If you used the file:// protocol, the ‘file://‘ is completely replaced by https://,
2. If you used a UNC path, all of the back slashes are converted to forward slashes with https:// prepended to the path.

The above applies even if you attempt to escape the UNC path’s backslashes like this:
Original UNC path:  \server\shared-folder
Escaped UNC path:  //\server/\shared-folder
The escaped UNC path will result in only forward slashes appearing in the link, prepended by https://